# How to allow the end user to select fonts within app?

Tags: java, android, android-fonts

As the title states, I just want to make a radiobuttons that allow user to select custom fonts for the entire app.

Can someone share a guide for that? I searched a lot but couldn't find anything.

Comment: Please note that Android is the platform and Android Studio is the tool that you use to create Android Apps.

Comment: i know that, my a bad i have the app on Google play right now its story type app just want to add buttons that allow user to select the font. i need the code is there is a way to save ttf file to the string?

Comment: More of a response to your posted answer, when posting questions you should say what you have found, perhaps other methods you have attempted that have failed, and even the code you have written so far (just in case you are really close).

Comment: Sorry I'm still new here. just i posted wut I have found and worked for me want to share it. since i searched a lot and didn't find any with alertdialog but after a lot of attempt it was a cake, ty :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since no one ans. 
Here is what i found.

just add fonts to assets Folder for exmple 
-font1.ttf
-font2.ttf
-font3.ttf
then,

```
CharSequence[] fonts = {"cous_font1","cous_font2","cous_font3"};



builder1.setSingleChoiceItems(fonts, -1, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                        switch (which){

                            case 0:
                                typeface = Typeface.createFromAsset(getAssets(), "font1_ttf");
                                yourtextView.setTypeface(typeface);
                                break;
                            case 1:
                                typeface2 = Typeface.createFromAsset(getAssets(), "Font2_ttf");
                                yourtextView.setTypeface(typeface2);
                                break;
                            case 2:
                                typeface2 = Typeface.createFromAsset(getAssets(), "font3_ttf");
                                yourtextView.setTypeface(typeface2);
```